# c# and networking - Client listening and server send and most efficient C# socket networking?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

I'm working on a game that depends on the standard System.Net.Sockets library for networking. What's the most efficient and standardized "system" I should use? Should the client send data requests every set amount of seconds, when a certain event happens? My other question, is a port forward required for a client to listen and receive data? How is this done, is there another socket created specifically for listening only on the client? How can I send messages and listen on the same socket on the client? I'm having a difficult time grasping the concept of networking, I started messing with it two days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a stable, high quality server will require you to have a wealth of knowledge on networking and managing your objects.

I highly recommend you start with something smaller before attempting to create your own server from scratch, or at the very least play around with a server for a different game that's already made, attempt to improve upon it or add new features.

That being said, there are a few ways you can setup the server, if you plan on having more than a couple of clients you don't generally want them to all send data whenever they feel like it as this can bog down the server, you want to structure it in such a way that the client sends as little data as possible on a scheduled basis and the server can request more when its ready. How that's setup and structured is up to you.

A server generally has to have a port forwarded on the router in order for requests to make it to the server from the internet, and here is why. When your computer makes a connection to a website (stackoverflow for example) it sends out a request on a random port, the router remembers the port that you sent out on and remembers who sent it (you), when the server sends the information you requested back the router knows you wanted that data and sends it back to you, in the case of RUNNING a server there is no outbound request to a client (Jack for example), so the router doesnt know where jacks request is supposed to go. By adding a port forwarding rule in the router your saying that all information passed to port 25565 (for example) is supposed to go to your server.

Clients generally do not need to forward ports because they are only making outbound requests and receiving data.

```
Server Starts, server starts listening on port 25565

Client starts, client connects to server on port 25565 and initiates a connection

Server responds to client on whatever port the client used to connect (this is done behind the scenes in sockets)

Communication continues from here.
```

Comment: What would you recommend I do if I'm very new to socket networking? I know how to start an asynchronous server listener and have the client connect and get output from the server when that happens, I'm just having trouble understanding how the server is going to be able to send messages to the client (which will receive them)

Comment: If you're intent on doing this, the client needs to connect to the server, which it does in the same way you connect to webpages, no rules are necessary aside from possibly being allowed through the local firewall, once you are connected information can be exchanged freely. The client can receive messages as long as the connection is open, or it can connect at intervals to check for messages. As a note, you may have issues running a socket indefinitely, I would recommend refreshing the socket connection from time to time.

Comment: Thank you. I will re-attempt my code and see if I can get it working. I have will have more confidence once I get the client to be able to send and receive data as well as the server.

Answer (score 1):

> Should the client send data requests every set amount of seconds, when a certain event happens?

No. Send your message as soon as you can. The socket stack has algorithms that determine when data is actually sent. For instance the Nagle algorithm.

However, if you send a LOT of messages it can be beneficial to enqueue everything in the same socket method call. However, you need to send several thousand of messages per client and second for that to give you any benefit.

> My other question, is a port forward required for a client to listen and receive data?

No. Once a socket connection have been established it's bidirectional. i.e. both end points and send and receive information without screwing something up for the other end point.

But to achieve that you typically have to use asynchronous operations so that you can keep receiving all the time.

> How is this done, is there another socket created specifically for listening only on the client?

The server has a dedicated socket (a listener) which only purpose is to accept client sockets. When the listener have accepted a new connection from a remote end  point you get a new socket object which represents the connection to the newly connected endpoint.

> How can I send messages and listen on the same socket on the client?

The easiest way is to use asynchronous receives and blocking sends.

If you do not want to take care of everything by yourself, you can try my Apache licensed library http://sharpmessaging.net.

Comment: fantastic thanks, @jgauffin.   I ended up using websocket sharp in the Unity (ie, C#/.Net) apps.  And, the server side is a hand-written Node server (using the ws library for websockets on that side)  Is sharpmessaging still active ?